# Finding MFLOPS using Linux 

Tags: performance, cpu

How can I find out the Mflops on my linux computer? I can see the bogomips on my /proc/cpuinfo but I don't see any Mflops on that file:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -ie mips -ie flops

bogomips    : 3591.29
bogomips    : 3590.96
bogomips    : 3590.96
bogomips    : 3590.96
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar question asked here - [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/88357/estimate-flops-in-linux)

The person who asked the question was pleased with [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a static number you can just read out of some register, it's a measure of how many floating point calculations you can actually do. However, there are both a variety of variations on this operation that some processors will be better at than others and it's affected by a lot of other factors in a system besides the CPU, so it's not an easy thing to measure.

See this [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/88357/40193) for some ideas on how to estimate it and benchmark software that can be used.